# effective Overlapping of dialog windows in Visual C++ 6

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

Hello there I have issue with overlapping of child windows,I have created a software with menu driven interface( IDR_MAINFRAME - CFormView

etc) and upon clicking one of the menu items another child-window appears( Dialog based ) where I do the calculations as a normal

calculator.Now if I open any other entry say conversion of metrics which is also in menu entry then on overlapping with any other such

window the background windows gets horribly disfigured and if i move about the calculator or the metrics conversion calculator randomly

they get disfigured and its a mess.Also I have put up a bitmap image on the background.Upon moving the calculator the background image also
gets erased.

Please let me know about how to handle this issue.I have googled and found that handling of paint messages or WM_ERASEBKGND helps ..but I

have tried this piece of code which just doesn't help in OnEraseBkGnd();

```
BOOL COfficesoftDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) 
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    CRect Rect;
    GetClientRect(Rect);
    //ClientToScreen(&Rect);
    //this->ScreenToClient(&Rect);
    this->InvalidateRect(Rect);
    return CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}
```

how can i achieve the smooth overlapping of different windows like a notepad overlapping a word document or even a calculator or even a VC6

IDE in my project.
Please explain it with an example .I am just a newbie and I need to understand in detail...thanks and regards

Comment: VC++6 is very old. You should update your compiler.

Comment: hello @David and @DeadMG ...i know i am working on something old but VC6 is last non .NET version IDE and I cant help it,here its part of the project ..anyways I have no clue as to make it more acceptable...I havent included something related to MFC's working...may be I am stupid :) ..I am just a newbie trying to get things worked since I have a deadline.Anyways I am using a MFC way I guess ...please show to me with example the way to do it according to the MFC way strictly and not the standard one.Please show me a sample project ..thanks and sorry if I am too demanding ...thanks again

Comment: go over your previous questions and accept the answer that is most helpful. Read more in the faq.

Answer (score 0):

1. Override OnEraseBkgnd and return true so it stops erasing the background you're painting. Returning TRUE says that you've done the work. If you simply call the base class implementation, it's going to do this for you, and you'll lose the background until it gets a chance to paint.
2. You're not getting paint messages to the parent window for some reason. Make sure you're calling the modal in the correct manner. DoModal() works fine. Make sure you're not just creating the modal and showing it.
3. If your windows are children on the same dialog/window and they overlap or you have children on either dialog/window, make sure that you use clipchildren and clipsiblings (if children on a window overlap). Otherwise they'll get to paint in any order they choose artifacting all over the place.
4. Ensure that you're painting to memory and bitblting back to your dialog, otherwise you'll get a flashing effect.